# Doubts related to Spark resource usage

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, rdd

I am executing a Spark Streaming application and I am caching the rdds for history look-back, my batch is of duration one minute and average processing time is 14 seconds, So executors are not computing for whole batch duration. So are executors, are still hold up  as I am caching the rdds in memory. And if executors are hold up should we consider this holding up of executors is wastage of resources.

Answer (score 0):

It depends of what you want to achieve.

In Spark 2.0, dynamic allocation is enabled to [Spark Streaming](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-12133) with no Bugs.

What was the problem, if you have a huge workload of data if you don't keep at least one executor for the data receive you may lose data. Now this is solved with Spark 2.0 and the release of the data is working.

What is the advantage of keeping your data in cache when a huge amount of data comes? You can process your data without a shuffle, it can increase your response time.

But, if you have a process of 1 by 1 minute. And it takes just 14 seconds to process your data in an average time. I suggest you to release your data and release your workers to open space for other tasks.

If you will not have enough resources for your tasks, the tasks will be queued and will be handled as soon you have the resources.

What is the risk? If you release the workers could be hard to get the resources back if you don't have [preemption](https://br.hortonworks.com/blog/better-slas-via-resource-preemption-in-yarns-capacityscheduler/) in your Yarn. This can be a waste of resource depends of your cluster.

What I would do is: create some queues that can handle your jobs. Set the High priority queue, set your streaming there, the other jobs in other queues and turn on the Dynamic Allocation and release the cache. If your application needs something with more resources the Yarn will handle it.

Comment: "I suggest you to release your data " , I can't release my data as I need it for next iteration for history purpose.

Comment: Is your data really Huge? You check all entries of your data for each input of your stream?

Comment: Yes I check all entries of data and have size of data is ~200KB